# JavaScript filter hueRotate does not work

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change an image's (`#bgImage`) hue when hovering over a button (`profIcon`) in JavaScript. This type of button is created with JS, and there are 9 of them.

Here is the code that creates a `DOM image element`, sets it's source, position, size and transition. Finally it appends it to it's container. The image appears correctly, where it should be.

I am using `quickID` in place of `document.getElementById`, and it is working without error.

```
var bgImage = document.createElement("img");
bgImage.id = "bgImage";
bgImage.src = "./resources/images/backgrounds/profession/selector.jpg";
bgImage.style.position = "absolute";
bgImage.style.left = "0px";
bgImage.style.top = "0px";
bgImage.style.width = "100%";
bgImage.style.height = "100%";
bgImage.style.zIndex = 1;
bgImage.style.webkitTransition = "all 0.5s ease";
quickID("centerdiv").appendChild(bgImage);
```

Here is the code that runs when I hover over an image:

```
profIcon.onmouseover = function () {
    var thisNr = this.id.substr(8); //last char of the profIcon ID; number between 0 and 8
    var newHue = profTomb[thisNr][3]; //this contains the value and only that.
    console.log(newHue); //always returns the correct value
    quickID(this.id).style.webkitFilter = "grayscale(0%)"; //this part works, too
    quickID("bgImage").style.webkitFilter = "hueRotate(" + newHue + "deg)";
}
```

My problem: for some reason, the filter does not apply. `newHue` is either a positive (75), or a negative (-23) value and it's inserted correctly, as it appears in the console log. I only use `webkit` vendor prefix as I use Google Chrome.

I waited up to 1 minute with my mouse cursor over the image, thinking my system needs time to process the transformation, but nothing happened.

Does anyone knows what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct string to use is `hue-rotate`, not `hueRotate`. The following should work:

```
quickID("bgImage").style.webkitFilter = "hue-rotate(" + newHue + "deg)";
```

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem! For some reason I though I should use camelCase in the filter's name too.

Comment: The properties of the `style` object are camelCased so you can use the dot notation (`style.webkitFilter`) instead of needing to write `style['webkit-filter']`. In javascript, if a property has a `-` in its name, it can only be accessed using the brackets `[ ]`.